# column in worksheet paste and sort data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data that I'm copying from one sheet to another. Here is my list of data. My goal is to move Column A from Sheet 1 to Column B in Sheet 2 and sort the data from "a" to "b" to "c"...basically in alphabetical order.
For example: Column A contains (a, a, a, b ,c a, b, d, a, b, a) and I want it to be arranged in Column B of Sheet 2 like this (a, a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, d). Below is my code. Please help if you can.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
'Conditional if statement that copies "a's" in Sheet 1, Column A and pastes in Sheet 2, Column B
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "a" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Copy
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i + 1).Select
            
                        
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i + 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan
            'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Borders.Color = rbgBlack
        End If
    
        'Deletes empty cells and shifts "a's" upward
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
                        Columns("B:B").Select
                        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
              
'Conditional if statement that copies data in Sheet 1, Column B and pastes in Sheet 2, Column C
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "a" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Copy
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i + 1).Select
                        
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        
        'Deletes empty cells and shifts data upward in Column C
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
                        Columns("C:C").Select
                        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        
    Next i
          
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems you are making it waaay too hard for yourself.  Fire up the macro recorder, select column A in Sheet1, copy -> select column B in Sheet2, paste -> click the 'sort A-Z button', stop the macro recorder.  That should really be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are complicating yourself too much. This should work:

```
    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B" & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

It takes ColumnA of Sheet1, cuts its contents and pastes them in ColumnB of Sheet2, before sorting them in alphabetical order.

Best,
C.